# Jmeter Webdriver sampler error for Firefox web driver

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, selenium-firefoxdriver, jmeter-3.2

I am using Jmeter version is 3.2, firefox webdriver version 2.33, firefox browser version is 46 and my Sampler is like:

```
Thread Group
   jp@gc Web Driver Sampler
     jp@gc-Firefox Driver Config
```

When I run the sample test I get the below error:

```
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:244) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:110) ~[selenium-remote-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:188) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:183) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:100) ~[selenium-firefox-driver-2.33.0.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.createBrowser(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:41) ~[JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar:?]
    at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.FirefoxDriverConfig.threadStarted(FirefoxDriverConfig.java:22) ~[JMeterPlugins-WebDriver.jar:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread$ThreadListenerTraverser.addNode(JMeterThread.java:677) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:996) ~[jorphan%20-%20Copy.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverseInto(HashTree.java:997) ~[jorphan%20-%20Copy.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree.traverse(HashTree.java:978) ~[jorphan%20-%20Copy.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.threadStarted(JMeterThread.java:646) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.initRun(JMeterThread.java:634) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:3.2 r1790748]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
tInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\Shadab_Quddus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous903713617974027002webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":false,"v":"2.33.0","st":1506749918112,"mt":1506749918081}},"app-system-defaults":{"e10srollout@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\e10srollout@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0","st":1462247100000},"firefox@getpocket.com":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\firefox@getpocket.com.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.0","st":1462247100000},"loop@mozilla.org":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\features\\loop@mozilla.org.xpi","e":true,"v":"1.2.6","st":1462247100000}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}.xpi","e":true,"v":"46.0.1","st":1462247100000}}}
1506749921723   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into [Selenium ChangeLog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG) I'm afraid `selenium-firefox-driver-2.33.0.jar` will support at most Firefox 20 so you will need to downgrade your Firefox version. You can download previous Firefox version(s) from [Mozilla FTP website](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/)

Another option is upgrading to latest version of [JMeter WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin, you can do it using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/). As per WebDriver Sampler version 1.4.0 you should get `selenium-firefox-driver-2.52.0.jar` which should support Firefox 46.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) article for more information on JMeter and Selenium integration.